# VS Code - How to connect to remote repository

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-ec2, visual-studio-code, remote-access, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have AWS EC2 instance, where I have pulled github repo and hosting my `staging app` through it.
I would like to connect to repo available on AWS EC2. so that I can see my changes on `staging` as soon as I update code inside the repo.

Any help or suggestion will be appriciated.

Note : `Feel free to edit the question for clear understanding.`

Comment: What is the OS of the AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: @abdullahkhawer It is Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This [vscode-remote-ssh](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/07/25/remote-ssh) blog helped me.